# install addin from O365 exclude

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, manifest, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a manifest file for an Outlook add-on on macOS that requires o356 for deploying to user mailboxes.

However, I have encountered a small problem as some of my users have workstations running both macOS and Windows.
When I install the add-on, it installs on two computers for the user.

However, the add-on was designed for MacOS and when installed on Windows, it causes issues with Outlook's efficiency.

Have you experienced this problem?

In the JavaScript script added to LessFunctionFileUrl, I have included operating system validation.

```
function operatingSytem() { 
    var contextInfo = Office.context.diagnostics;
    printLog('Office application: ' + contextInfo.host)
    printLog('Platform: ' + contextInfo.platform)
    printLog('Office version: ' + contextInfo.version)

    // To debug into web broswer console 
    // add the comparison below into the if condition
    //contextInfo.platform == 'OfficeOnline'
    if(contextInfo.platform == 'Mac'){
        return 'MacOS';
    }
    return 'Other'
}

function validateBody(event) {
    Office.onReady().then(function() {
        //TODO The message id must be changed to proper replace the message 
        // "Addin is working on your request."
        //Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("succeeded", {
            //type: "progressIndicator",
            //message: "Microsoft is working on your request.",
        //});
        printLog(" email validation started - [v1.2]")
        //Execute the add-in logic only if it is Outlook application running on MacOS
        if(operatingSytem() == "MacOS"){
            printLog("MacOS detected")
            validate(event).catch(data => {handleError(data, event)});
        } else{
            printLog("OS is not MacOS")
            handleError("Not MacOS", event);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, this only gives the add-on the ability to not analyze the email. And the problem begins to occur after the installation itself.

Comment: I'd suggest starting from Outlook's efficiency problems on Windows instead of suppressing the add-in at all. Try posting your problem in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to avoid the add-in doing its business logic on Windows by checking the [platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=common-js-preview#office-office-context-platform-member) property of the `Office.Context` interface at runtime. You can check the platform and set a flag whether to run add-in callbacks or not. This flag can be used in add-in callbacks, not in the `onReady` callback to run a validation logic.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your reply.
I just don't quite know how to do it can you write me a code example of how to do it so that it will guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the code this way can you verify?

```
let shouldRunAddinCallbacks = true; // Flag to control callback execution based on platform

// Function to check the platform and set the flag
function checkPlatformAndSetFlag() {
    if (Office.context && Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PCWindows) {
        shouldRunAddinCallbacks = false; // Do not run add-in callbacks on Windows platform
    }
}

// Call this function when the add-in initializes
Office.initialize = function () {
    checkPlatformAndSetFlag(); // Check platform and set flag
    // Existing initialization code follows...
}



let logEnable = false;

function sleep(delay) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}

Office.initialize = function () {
    checkPlatformAndSetFlag();
}

function printLog(text) {
    console.log(text);
    if(logEnable &&
        (typeof text === 'string' || text instanceof String))
    {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("succeeded", {
            type: "progressIndicator",
            message: text.substring(0, Math.min(text.length, 250)),
        });
        sleep(1500);
    }
}
async function httpServerCheck(resolve, reject){
    printLog("Checking the server");
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        controller.abort();},
        30000)

    fetch('https://localhost:55296/FirefoxExt/_1',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'cors',
                cache: 'no-cache',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
            }
        ).then(response => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (!response.ok) {
                printLog("Server is down");
                reject(false)
            }
            printLog("Server is UP");
            resolve(true)
        }).catch(e => {
            printLog(e);
            printLog("Request crashed");
            reject(false)
        });
}

async function sendToClasifier(url = '', data = {}, event) {
    printLog("Sending event to classifier");
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        controller.abort();},
        30000)
    fetch(url, {
        signal: controller.signal,
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            printLog("Engine returned error: "+response.json());
            handleError(response, event);
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(response => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        handleResponse(response, event);
    }).catch(e => {
        printLog(e);
        printLog("Request crashed");
        handleError(e, event);
    });
}

function handleResponse(data, event) {
    printLog("Handling response from engine");
    message = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    if (data["action"] === 1) {
        message.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Blocked by DLP engine' });
        printLog("DLP block");
        event.completed({ allowEvent: false });
    } else if (data["action"] === 0) {
        printLog("Completing event: DLP Allow");
        printLog("DLP allow");
        event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    } else {
        printLog("Completing event: Unrecognized JSON response: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        printLog("Unrecognized JSON response: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    }
}

async function tryPost(event, subject, from, to, cc, bcc, body, attachments) {
        printLog("Trying to post")
        let data = {
            "subject": subject,
            "body": body,
            "from": from,
            "to": to,
            "cc": cc,
            "bcc": bcc,
            "attachments": attachments
        };
        if(data['attachments']){
            printLog("Attachment list size: "+data['attachments'].length)            
        }
        sendToClasifier('https://localhost:55296/OutlookAddin', data, event)
}

async function postMessage(message, event, subject, from, to, cc, bcc, body, attachments){
    printLog("Posting message")
    if(attachments !== null){
        await Promise.all(
                attachments.value.map(attachment => {
                    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                        message.getAttachmentContentAsync(attachment.id, data => {
                        let att = {
                            "file_name": attachment.name,
                            "data": data.value.content,
                            "content_type": attachment.contentType
                        };
                        //printLog(att)
                        resolve(att)
                        })
                        setTimeout(() => {resolve(null)}, 30000)
                    })
                })
            )
            .then(result => {
                tryPost(event, subject, from, to, cc, bcc, body, result.filter(Boolean));
            })
    }else{
        tryPost(event, subject, from, to, cc, bcc, body, []);
    }
}

function getIfVal(result)
{
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        return result.value;
    }
    return "";
}


async function validate(event) {
    message = Office.context.mailbox.item;

    if (message.itemType == "appointment") {
        printLog("Validating appointment")
        await Promise.all([
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    httpServerCheck(resolve, reject)
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.subject.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.organizer.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    }) 
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.requiredAttendees.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.optionalAttendees.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 5000)
                    message.body.getAsync("html", {asyncContext: event}, result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve(null)}, 5000)
                    message.getAttachmentsAsync(result => {
                        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded &&
                                result.value.length > 0) {
                            resolve(result)
                        }
                        resolve(null)
                    })
                })
        ]).then(values => {
            postMessage(message, event, result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], [], result[5], result[6]);
        }).catch(err => {
            handleError("Server might be down", event);
        });
    } else if (message.itemType == "message") {
        printLog("Validating message")
        await Promise
            .all([
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    httpServerCheck(resolve, reject)
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.subject.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),                    
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.from.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.to.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.cc.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 3000)
                    message.bcc.getAsync(result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve("")}, 5000)
                    message.body.getAsync("html", {asyncContext: event}, result => {
                        resolve(getIfVal(result))
                    })
                }),
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {resolve(null)}, 5000)
                    message.getAttachmentsAsync(result => {
                        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded &&
                                result.value.length > 0) {
                            resolve(result)
                        }
                        resolve(null)
                    })
                })
                ])
            .then(result => {
                postMessage(message, event, result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7]);
            }) .catch(err => {
                printLog(err.message)
                handleError("Server might be down", event);
            });

    } else {
        printLog("message item type unknown");
        printLog(message.itemType);
        handleError("Unknown Message Type", event)
    }
}

function handleError(data, event) {
    printLog(data);
    printLog(event);
    printLog("Completing event ")
    event.completed({ allowEvent: true });
    printLog("Event Completed")
}

function operatingSytem() { 
    var contextInfo = Office.context.diagnostics;
    printLog('Office application: ' + contextInfo.host)
    printLog('Platform: ' + contextInfo.platform)
    printLog('Office version: ' + contextInfo.version)

    // To debug into web broswer console 
    // add the comparison below into the if condition
    //contextInfo.platform == 'OfficeOnline'
    if(contextInfo.platform == 'Mac'){
        return 'MacOS';
    }
    return 'Other'
}

function validateBody(event) {
    Office.onReady().then(function() {
        //TODO The message id must be changed to proper replace the message 
        // "Forcepint One is working on your request."
        //Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("succeeded", {
            //type: "progressIndicator",
            //message: "Microsoft is working on your request.",
        //});
        printLog("FP email validation started - [v1.2]")
        //Execute the add-in logic only if it is Outlook application running on MacOS
        if(operatingSytem() == "MacOS"){
            printLog("MacOS detected")
            validate(event).catch(data => {handleError(data, event)});
        } else{
            printLog("OS is not MacOS")
            handleError("Not MacOS", event);
        }
    });
}


if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
//    printLog("Export defined")
    exports.handleResponse = handleResponse;
    exports.handleError = handleError;
    exports.postData = postData;
    exports.validateBody = validateBody;

}
```